# What is WITH-STANDARD-IO-SYNTAX macro for?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

The [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-a-simple-database.html) page 25, explains the WITH-STANDARD-IO-SYNTAX as follows. "It ensures that certain variables that affect the behavior of PRINT are set to their standard values".

The usage is as follows.

```
(with-open-file (...)
    (with-standard-io-syntax
        (print ...
```

Should (print) be used in this macro? If not, what would happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Various dynamic variables affect the output produced by `print`.  `with-standard-io-syntax` ensures those variables are set to the default values.

For example:

```
(let ((list '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
      (*print-length* 5))
  (print list)
  (with-standard-io-syntax
    (print list)))
```

Prints:

```
(1 2 3 4 5 ...) 
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

It's particularly important if you're printing things with the intention of being able to `read` them later (like with `prin1`).